# How to stop visual studio from changing properties of controls in WPF form when I add a new control to form using Designer?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I'm using visual studio ultimate 2010. In WPF form, I've a grid which contains many controls. Whenever I try to add a new control to the grid using designer, visual studio changes properties of all other controls in some way, like Grid.Row, Grid.Column property. Because of this I've to change those properties back manually. How can I stop visual studio from changing properties of certain controls in the wpf form? Is there any way that I can lock some controls in WPF form so that their properties doesn't change.
Easy solution would be appreciated.
Thank You.

I've seen some questions related to this but didn't find a good solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The designer will change attached layout-related properties of existing controls if you add new controls in places which cause the existing controls to move, so really it just boils down to being careful where you add new things.

Or do what we've ended up doing, which is almost entirely abandoning the designer. Most of what we build is built in XAML by hand and it's a far better experience once you're familiar with it as you can control every aspect. The designer's good for throwing something together quickly, but if you want it behave precisely as you desire you're going to have to get into the XAML at some point.

Especially once you start writing data templates.

Comment: I guess so, if I don't find something useful today then I'll have to work in XAML for most of the things.

Answer (score 1):

The designer sucks. if you're doing lots of things consider copy and pasting xaml.
Alternatively if your creating lots and lots of elements 9which is sounds like you might be) do it in some for loop, something like this:

```
nameofgrid.Children.Add(listoftextblocks[i]);
Grid.SetColumn(listoftextblocks[i], 0);
Grid.SetRow(listoftextblocks[i], i + 1)
```

hopefully someone can be of more help with editor in particular, i find you have to be very careful where you place things with the mouse, but i hope these tips would be of some use.

Comment: Yeah, that's helpful, but hoping some better solution.